# PCRE to capture indefinite number of tokens individually

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some set of tokens that interest me, e.g.

*foo bar mumble fratz*.

The number of tokens to be scanned varies from 0 to n, can be in any order, and can include tokens that are not interesting.

Given a list

*bar fratz gorp*

*(foo|bar|mumble|fratz)*

will capture *bar*.  But it won't capture *fratz*.  It just backtracks and stops, satisfied.  Even giving it a *{2,}* clue doesn't make a difference.

There's some bit of syntax I'm missing, but I've played with regexbuddy (nice program, btw) til I'm blue in the face without being able to discover the problem.

Comment: Usually there is some kind of global modifier which might help you.

Comment: It won't capture `bar` it won't capture `fratz`. it will capture `foo`. Show the complete code you've used.

Comment: Which language are you working in? And is this for Perl or PCRE (you tagged both)?

Comment: @sln: It will **not** capture `foo` - there is no `foo` in the string after all.

Comment: *And is this for Perl or PCRE (you tagged both)?*

PCRE - someone else added the Perl tag

Comment: Perl tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does capture all of them if you tell the engine to search for all, e.g. in `PHP` the function is called `preg_match_all()` or `re.findall()` in `Python`.
General speaking, your regex works, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rL4pR7/1) (the `g` modifier on the right emulates the functions mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks!  The g switch (which RegexBuddy doesn't seem to implement) appears to do the trick.

Comment: I misinterpreted the role of greediness, thinking that it operates both within and between matches, not just seeing to consume the largest number of chars per match, but find the largest number of matches.  A logical idea, but incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `/g` (global) regex modifier to get all matches:

```
$ perl -E '$x = "foo blah bar mumble baz fratz"; @matches = $x =~ /(foo|bar|mumble|fratz)/g; say join "\n", @matches'
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
mumble
fratz
```